# Dynamically select multiple lines in a tkinter listbox

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a listbox that has about 30 entries in it. However, I cannot figure out how to select multiple lines from the listbox in code. Is there a method like `listbox.select(4,5,14)` that will allow me to do this?

Comment: Check out [`selection_set()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm#Tkinter.Listbox.selection_set-method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:-

```
#Here list_of_indexes_to_be_selected contains the indexes of items to be selected

for index in list_of_indexes_to_be_selected:
    listbox.select_set(index)
```

or you can try:-

```
for index in list_of_indexes_to_be_selected:
    listbox.selection_set(index)
```

Both are working

NOTE:- you need to make sure to pass selectmode='multiple' while creating listbox object.